# Use Bluetooth to control Arduino from IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've receive my arduino BLE module : SH-HC-08 I now how to use it regarding Android code. I also succeeded to communicate from an IOS app to my arduino by using an app from the app store. Now I would like to create my own app to control my arduino project.

I've been already trying a lot of tutorial available on the web but nothing work ... 
But this one look like to be good : [Tuto that I follow](http://make.analogfolk.com/getting-started-with-ios10-swift-and-bluetooth-4-0-for-wearables-hardware/)

To work my Arduino need to receive this value as string :

```
"0" -> Place the Servo in positon 0 
"180" -> Place the Servo in position 180
```

Here is my arduino code :

in `void setup()`

```
  bluetoothSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Prêt");
  bluetoothSerial.setTimeout(300);
  servo.attach(7, 0, 180);
  servo.write(0);
```

in my `void loop()`

```
if(bluetoothSerial.available()){
    c = bluetoothSerial.readString();

    Serial.println(c);

    if(c=="0"){
      servo.write(0);
    }
    if(c=="180"){
      servo.write(180);
    }
  }
```

By using the Appstore BLE communication app this works very well !

Now with my app nothing happens when I send `"180"` or `"0"` ...

My iOS Code :

In the mainViewController :

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var manager:CBCentralManager? = nil
    var mainPeripheral:CBPeripheral? = nil
    var mainCharacteristic:CBCharacteristic? = nil

    let BLEService = "DFB0"
    let BLECharacteristic = "DFB1"

    @IBOutlet weak var recievedMessageText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil);

        customiseNavigationBar()

    }

   // ................... CustomiseNavigationBar() were here

        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        rightBarButton.customView = rightButton
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "scan-segue") {
            let scanController : ScanTableViewController = segue.destination as! ScanTableViewController

            //set the manager's delegate to the scan view so it can call relevant connection methods
            manager?.delegate = scanController
            scanController.manager = manager
            scanController.parentView = self
        }

    }

    // MARK: Button Methods
    @objc func scanButtonPressed() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "scan-segue", sender: nil)
    }

    @objc func disconnectButtonPressed() {
        //this will call didDisconnectPeripheral, but if any other apps are using the device it will not immediately disconnect
        manager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(mainPeripheral!)
    }

    @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let helloWorld = "180"
        let dataToSend = helloWorld.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        if (mainPeripheral != nil) {
            mainPeripheral?.writeValue(dataToSend!, for: mainCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

            print(dataToSend)
        } else {
            print("haven't discovered device yet")
        }

    }

    // MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        mainPeripheral = nil
        customiseNavigationBar()
        print("Disconnected" + peripheral.name!)
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print(central.state)
    }

    // MARK: CBPeripheralDelegate Methods
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

        for service in peripheral.services! {

            print("Service found with UUID: " + service.uuid.uuidString)

            //device information service
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

            //GAP (Generic Access Profile) for Device Name
            // This replaces the deprecated CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

            //Bluno Service
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        //get device name
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A00") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found Device Name Characteristic")
                }

            }

        }

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A29") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found a Device Manufacturer Name Characteristic")
                    mainCharacteristic = characteristic
                } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A23") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found System ID")
                    mainCharacteristic = characteristic
                }

            }

        }

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BLECharacteristic) {
                    //we'll save the reference, we need it to write data
                    mainCharacteristic = characteristic

                    //Set Notify is useful to read incoming data async
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                    print("Found Bluno Data Characteristic")
                }

            }

        }

    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {


        if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A00") {
            //value for device name recieved
            let deviceName = characteristic.value
            print(deviceName ?? "No Device Name")
        } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A29") {
            //value for manufacturer name recieved
            let manufacturerName = characteristic.value
            print(manufacturerName ?? "No Manufacturer Name")
        } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A23") {
            //value for system ID recieved
            let systemID = characteristic.value
            print(systemID ?? "No System ID")
        } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BLECharacteristic) {
            //data recieved
            if(characteristic.value != nil) {
                let stringValue = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

                recievedMessageText.text = stringValue
            }
        }


    }

}
```

And my ScanTableViewController :

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ScanTableViewController: UITableViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var peripherals:[CBPeripheral] = []
    var manager:CBCentralManager? = nil
    var parentView:MainViewController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        scanBLEDevices()
    }    

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return peripherals.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scanTableCell", for: indexPath)
        let peripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = peripheral.name

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let peripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]

        manager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    // MARK: BLE Scanning
    func scanBLEDevices() {
        //manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID.init(string: parentView!.BLEService)], options: nil)

        //if you pass nil in the first parameter, then scanForPeriperals will look for any devices.
        manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

        //stop scanning after 3 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            self.stopScanForBLEDevices()
        }
    }

    func stopScanForBLEDevices() {
        manager?.stopScan()
    }

    // MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if(!peripherals.contains(peripheral)) {
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print(central.state)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

        //pass reference to connected peripheral to parent view
        parentView?.mainPeripheral = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = parentView
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        //peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(<#T##characteristicUUIDs: [CBUUID]?##[CBUUID]?#>, for: <#T##CBService#>)

        //set the manager's delegate view to parent so it can call relevant disconnect methods
        manager?.delegate = parentView
        parentView?.customiseNavigationBar()

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

        print("Connected to " +  peripheral.name!)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(error!)
    }

}
```

I'm sorry about put a lot of code it isn't so clean but I totally don't know where is the problem ...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: We'll need information about what does happen and what doesn't happen. You have a number of print statements. Which ones print? Do you see errors in the logs (the most likely one is something like "API Misuse" because you're probably scanning before the bluetooth central powers on, but it's hard to tell from this code without information about your logs). Focus just on the code that actually scans, connects, and communicates. The table view isn't important for bluetooth communication.

Comment: Your Arduino code also doesn't match the tutorial. I would start by exactly following the tutorial so that you know it work as expected; then move from there. For example, you don't check Serial.available in your loop.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help ! But my problem was due to the parameter `mainPeripheral?.writeValue(dataToSend!, for: mainCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)` I replace the last part by `.withoutResponse` because my BLE module deal like that and it work perfectly fine now !